# Set Type Txt to show all line Batch File

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Please Help me .

I want To set Final.txt to variable in batch .

Inside Final.txt like this :

```
7-Zip 15.12 (x64)

Adobe Reader XI (11.0.10)

Advanced BAT to EXE Converter v2.94 

AIMP3
```

Comment: As you can see from the answer below there is a lot of code to do this in a batch file. Sometimes it is just easier to do this with a language that natively supports that feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "content="
set fileLocation=final.txt

for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%fileLocation%") do (
    set "content=!content!!NL!!%%#"
)
echo =======
echo %content%
echo =======
```